# Using explode on URL to get the array number of each string

Tags: php, arrays, url, explode

Hi I'm trying to get the controller from a url request for example:

```
$url = http://www.yourDomain.com/request/code
```

I'm using this code:
$control = array();

$control = explode('/', $url);

now i would like to get the 'request' string from that url so i use:

```
$get = $control[3];
```

I think I'm confuse about the numbering of the array since there is two slashes after `http:`

would array assign a number in between slashes?
something like this

```
$control[0] = http:
$control[1] = '';
$control[2] = www.yourDomain.com;
$control[3] = request;
$control[4] = code;
```

The part with double slashes confuses me.

Comment: Consider [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) for the basic separation. Or better yet [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) for asserting and extracting from the whole string. (Don't use `explode` for everything.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case a null value will also can be assigned to array so your array should be like this...

```
Array
(
   [0] => http:
   [1] => 
   [2] => www.yourDomain.com
   [3] => request
   [4] => code
)
```